# How to run Play with -feature?

Tags: scala, playframework

This is how I run Play:

```
activator ~run
```

I'm getting the following warnings:

```
[warn] there were 27 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
```

But if I run Play with this command I don't see the warning details:

```
activator ~run -feature
```

How to run Play with -feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `activator -feature ~run`

But this going to be deprecated in sbt 0.14.

You can setup this option to be used for every run. Add this to config file of your activator:
`~/.activator/activatorconfig.txt`

UPD.
`activatorconfig` is the similar to `sbtconfig.txt` and should contains all system props that you want pass to sbt/activator.

`activatorconfig` should be placed in one of the below folders:

```
set "CFG_FILE_HOME=%UserProfile%\.activator\activatorconfig.txt"
set "CFG_FILE_VERSION=%UserProfile%\.activator\%APP_VERSION%\activatorconfig.txt"
```

Check you `activator` start script for more details.

Comment: what should be the contents of activatorconfig.txt ?

Comment: just single line with `-feature` option.

Comment: this didn't work, can you be more specific? I have an `/.activator/1.3.7/` directory, is it there where I should create the file? what should be the content, simply a line with `-feature' ?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature")
```

in your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: where is the build.sbt located? I start activator but there's no build.sbt file in that directory.